# threeparttablex fails to provide \source and \tnotex

Tags: longtable, threeparttablex, tablenotes

I'm using the ThreePartTable enivornment (provided by threeparttablex) to add table notes to my longtable. However, I keep getting `! Undefined control sequence.` for `\notex` and `\source`.

I'm using TeXnicCenter (not that this should matter), and according to the MiKTeX Package Manager, threeparttablex is version 0.3.

As an MWE, here is the second example from the threeparttablex-manual (http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttablex/threeparttablex.pdf), augmented just by a preample

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs,}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\begin{document}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\item[a] \label{tn:a} test test test test test test test test
\item[b] \label{tn:b} test2
\source Made up by daleif
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtable}{l l l}
\caption{A long table}\\
\toprule
Coloum 1 & & Column 2 \\
\midrule
\endhead
\cmidrule{3-3}
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{continued}}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes\\
\endlastfoot
AAAA\tnotex{tn:a} & & BBBB \\
% \newpage
CC & & DD\tnotex{tn:b} \\
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The commands `\source` and `\tnotex` are available only if `threeparttablex` is called with the `referable` option: change the call into

```
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
```

and the example will work with no other change.

Comment: Well, people who came to this question didn't look three lines up in the [manual](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttablex/threeparttablex.pdf#page=2) where it talks about `\tnotex` (myself included). Thanks for saving our miserable lives egreg `:)`